# How to remove core js in magento 2

Tags: javascript, magento-2.2.5

I wish to remove password-strength-indicator.js and zxcvbn.js  from customer module, because it takes 1 MB to load and takes more time.
So Please provide me a solution to remove the above js what i have mentioned.

Comment: @Jai why do you add each time a `Possible duplicate of` that it is off topic ! you know what you do at least ? Please explain me what is the link between `remove js` and `error on custom id`

Answer (score 1):

You test

```
<remove src="zxcvbn.js"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove JS files of magento core however there is a possible workaround, that map / replace your js file with module js file using require-config.js of your theme ( placed in your theme folder) :

like :

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
       'Magento_Customer/js/JS_FILE_NAME':'Vendor_Module/js/REPLACED_FILE'     
     }
   }
};
```